# Is this a topology?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that we have a set $S$ containing 0 and 1. Can we define our topology to be the four open sets $\varnothing$, $\{0\}$, $\{1\}$ and $\{0,1\}$? I know that the Sierpinski set contains the three elements $\varnothing$, $\{0\}$, and $\{0,1\}$. I wonder if the fourth element is added, is it still a topology.

Comment: There are really just three axioms to check, and only four sets to check them with. Even if you do everything by hand, completely robotic, without optimization, it shouldn't take you longer than two hours to check that. And if you do it using your brain, then it should take only a couple of minutes.

Comment: I don't get it, unless $S = \{0,1\}$ it won't be. Just saying $S$ containing 0 and 1 obviously doesn't cut it.

Comment: @dioid: That appears to be OP's intent. $S=\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 4):

$\mathscr P(S)$ is a topology on $S$ for any set $S$, often called the *discrete* topology.

In this topology, every subset of $S$ is open, so every map defined on $S$ is continuous. Pretty simple, but extremely useful.

Comment: it should be a comment !

Comment: @idm: What do you mean? How does this not answer the question?

Comment: I did see it before it got corrected.  I'll remove the previous comment.

Comment: It may be boring, but it's danged useful for disproving a bunch of things,  like "do continuous functions preserve quality X".   Any quality that the discrete topology has automatically fails that test,  since you can always define a continues function from a space under the discrete topology to the same space under the actual topology as the identity map

Comment: $\mathscr P(S)$ is a topoly on $S$ but it only contains the four open sets stated in OP of $S$ unless $S$ contains any other elements. And unless that is the case the four elements won't be a topology.

Comment: @dioid: It appears to be OP's intent that $S=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @Alan: I agree completely. I use it all the time. By "boring" I simply mean "uncomplicated". I will amend my statement.

Comment: @MPW that's not what he/she said, but Ok, if that was the intent I rest my case.